# snapchat going to settings

Tags: settings, snapchat

Whenever I take a photo on snapchat it takes me to app settings. Ive gotten rid of other apps and uninstalled it then installed it again but nothing works.
This happens after i take a photo.

Comment: Usually if an app opens the Android settings for you it wants that you make certain changes, e.g. set a permission for the app so that it can access the camera.

Comment: Does this happen before taking a photo, or after taking a photo? If it's the former, then Robert's comment is the most likely. If it's the latter... that's weird?

Comment: This happens after I take a photo.